# Attach a number to string in a column based on condition in other columns in R

Tags: r

I would like to add a number to only `MATH` in column `course` based on the following condition; for each `ID` if `MATH` has `output` column equal to `pass` increase the attached number by 1 for the next `MATH`. here is an example:

```
df = read.table(text = 
'ID  course  outcome
 10  MATH    fail
 10  PHYS    pass
 10  MATH    pass
 10  MATH    fail
 10  CHEM    pass
 11  MATH    pass
 11  PHYS    fail
 12  CMP     pass
 12  MATH    fail
 12  MATH    fail
 12  CHEM    pass
 12  MATH    pass
 12  MATH    fail', header = T)


df_result = read.table(text = 
  'ID  course  outcome
   10  MATH1    fail
   10  PHYS     pass
   10  MATH1    pass
   10  MATH2    fail
   10  CHEM     pass
   11  MATH1    pass
   11  PHYS     fail
   12  CMP      pass
   12  MATH1    fail
   12  MATH1    fail
   12  CHEM     pass
   12  MATH1    pass
   12  MATH2    fail', header = T)
```

Please help me to do it in R

Comment: Is the number next to `MATH` supposed to start back at 1 if there's a `fail`? The label goes from `MATH2` at row 4 back down to `MATH1` at row 6.

Comment: @astrofunkswag, no it starts again from 1 if the `ID` change, as row 6 belongs to `ID` 11. `fail` does not change the number and only `pass` changes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick (using `dplyr`):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(math_pass_count = 1 + lag(cumsum(course == "MATH" & outcome == "pass"), 
                                   default = 0),
         suffix = ifelse(course == "MATH", math_pass_count, ""),
         course = paste0(course, suffix)) %>%
  select(-math_pass_count, -suffix)
```

Comment: it keeps increasing the suffix regardless of changing `ID`. I would like to reset to 1 for each `ID`

Comment: Did you forget to include the `group_by(ID)` line?

Comment: If you copy and paste all of the code on this page into a clean R session and add `library(dplyr)` you should find that the output of my code matches your `df_result` exactly, so I'm not sure what the problem might be.

(Matches exactly apart from data types with factors vs. character vectors)